# Vue warn: Property is not defined. Form input binding + conditional rendering

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some trouble with input binding and conditional rendering: e.g. if I select grade = 1, I want to show the date field. When I load the page, I get:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "grade" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

My form:

```
<form id="school">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('grade', 'Grade') !!}
        {!! Form::select('grade', $grades, null, ['v-model' => 'grade']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" v-show="grade == 1">
            {!! Form::label('date', 'Date') !!}
            {!! Form::date('date', null,) !!}
    </div>  
</form>
```

Vue instance:

```
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#school',
            data: {
                grade: 1
            }
        });
    </script>
```

What am I missing here? I am new to Vue and really want to learn more!

Edit:

When I look to the source code of my browser, I see that the `v-model` attribute has disappeared. E.g.: when I write `<input type="text" name="test" v-model="test">`, I see `<input type="text" name="test">`

Comment: `{!! Form::label` what type of syntax is that? I've been doing Vue.js professionally for more than a year, but never have seen that before.

Comment: @connexo https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#labels

Comment: So this is Vue on the server-side?

Comment: @connexo no. Laravel / PHP renders the HTML server side but Vue still operates in the browser

Comment: Then, wouldn't it make more sense to show the HTML that Vue actually sees?

Comment: Where is your `#school` element?

Comment: @connexo absolutely. This would make debugging the problem much easier

Comment: my form has the school id attribute

Comment: @Phil so Laravel is kind of a template tag library connecting PHP data to HTML?

Comment: @connexo Laravel is a PHP framework. It uses the Blade template library (the `{!!..` syntax).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Why is it that these new template engines are required to have pseudo-cool, childish-sounding names like "Blade", "Nunjucks" or "Razor"?

Comment: Lol at these comments. :D @user3253002 try to post the HTML (Right Click - View Source) of the page for us to see.

Comment: I see that when I render the page, the v-model attribute is gone ... driving me crazy! even when I don't use the `Form` facade and type `<input type="text" v-model="test">` .. It returns `<input type="text">`

Comment: after the page load, I can see the hidden elements for a sec and then they disappear ...

Comment: From the warning message, I can tell you the problem is not the `v-model` attribute, but the `data:` property in the `new Vue({...})` code. It doesn't have a  `grade` field. The one you posted in the question does, which leads us to believe something else is happening (maybe you are using other  `new Vue({...})` code, maybe something else removes the `grade`, who knows...).

Comment: @acdcjunior you got me in the right direction! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/cannot-use-vue-instance-in-laravel-blade)

So Laravel comes with a Vue instance..

Comment: _"So Laravel comes with a Vue instance"_ so what does that mean in the context of your question?

Comment: the `app.js` contains already a Vue instance (out of the box)